# copy/ paste data to/after the last row/column of data. from old workbook to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am updating a weekly Master file. As a result, I am trying to copy and paste the data from the source file to the Master sheet. Now, The data needs to be pasted to the columns and rows after the data of the previous week. So for example if last weeks data ends ("H70:M70"), I need the new pasted data to go to ("H71:M71"). Also, the new pasted data has many rows, so nexts week data has to be pasted after the last row/column of this weeks data i.e ("H230:M230"). Please Help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copydata()
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim thisWB As Workbook
Dim thisWS As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

Set myWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\test.xlsx")

myWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:F17").Copy

Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set thisWS = thisWB.Sheets("Test data")

thisWB.Activate
thisWS.Range("H71:M71").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

myWB.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `thisWS.Range("A1")` so instead of `A1` find last row and use that instead. Edit: it will take you 5min to figure out how to find last row ^_^

Comment: @findwindow. There is a lot of the data on the new pasted area. Which means, that the new data has to be 'specifically' pasted in a ranged areas. For example ("H71:M71").

Comment: That can be done really easily as well. That will take a little longer to figure out. Hint: google `resize`. Edit: well, since you're copy/pasting, that's irrelevant because you can just paste at last row. I suggest setting ranges to each other instead but then you need to `resize`.

Comment: I think the key here is the last row/column of data. The range seems simple enough, but it has to be automated, as such, that the new data is pasted after the last col/row of previous weeks data.

Comment: Like I said, that will take you **5min** to figure out. If it takes longer... this task may be beyond you and you should pay someone to do it XD

Comment: I have pasted the new data, where it should go. That was done in less than 5 mins. Its pasting the new data at the end of each row+1 is now the key. @findwindow thanks for your input.

Comment: I know you're trying to get him to learn on his own, but he came to SO for help after he got stuck. I don't think it's in the spirit of the site to tell someone they are simply unskilled enough to complete a task.

Comment: @SeanScott so you're saying OP couldn't google what you just posted below???

Comment: @JamesJordan it appears you lack the concept of a variable :/ That's something that will take longer to explain. I will let Sean help you.

Comment: @findwindow It is clearly a gray area, hence I did not flag you or anything like that. I think early users sometimes have trouble separating common concepts from the context of their question and can benefit from a short push. I'm happy to help from here.

Comment: @SeanScott I guess I find it incredibly obtuse for someone to _know_ they need to find xyz and fail to google xyz. Because googling "find last row excel" should get you the answer in 5 min? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James, are you familiar with `End()` in VBA?

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This will go to the last possible Cell in column 1 of your worksheet, then go up until it finds a Cell containing data and return the corresponding row.

The other possible arguments for `End()` are xlDown, xlToLeft, and xlToRight. They can be used to find last/first columns and rows.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will do some research on End(). I've seen it around, so it certainly has jogged my memory. Hence,its a place to start. Never mind 'findwindow', I am ok with his response. Some people have the time to help, others dont. Its cool with me. I am just learning all the same.

Comment: I think that's a great way to look at it. If you need any further assistance, please leave a comment, and if this solves your problem, please mark as answer!

Comment: Thanks Sean. Yes, I can take it from here. I think the key here was actually knowing where to start. As there is so much info out there, deciphering the actual information needed is the critical. Clearly you pointed me to the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: PS when you accept answers in the future, please vote up as well. We get more points that way! :P

Comment: Learn something new everyday. I didnt realise that. Makes sense! Thx